# Angular front-end and C# back-end in different VS solution

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio-2015

I have built a single-page-application with angular ui-routing in Visual Studio. This front-end application works well. Notes that I **don't** build this front-end based on MVC architecture. It is based on [angular seed's project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

**The problem:**

Now I need to build a C# back-end that handles api call. The criteria are:

1. It should be in different Visual Studio's solution. My client want the front-end to be static and when we decide for example, to change the back-end to python, we can just reuse the front-end.
2. Both should run on the same port. For example, now the front-end runs on localhost:13000. Then the back-end should run on localhost:13000/api.
3. Not using Nginx. This application will be installed on user's computer and installing Nginx is hard for amateur user.

**Possible Solution:**

1. Build the usual MVC. Where the Front-End and Back-End located on the same Visual Studio's solution. But this collides with criteria #1.
2. Build a separate solution for Front-End and Back-End. Each run on different port and communicate with each other. But there's a security issue and it also collides with criteria #2.
3. Use Nginx to "proxy" both port. But this collide with criteria #3.
4. Build a self-hosting C# Server that handles both request from Front-End and Back-End. Right now I'm trying to build it based on [David's simple web server](https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server). So far this satisfy all three criteria, but it only accepts "String" request. All picture and Glyphicons is not working. It will be a lot of work to configure the web server to accept all type of request.

**My Question:**

1. Are there easier way to do this? I've read a bit about OWIN but not sure if that's the one that I need for this problem.
2. If Solution #4 is the best way, are there some kind of guide upon how to configure my web server correctly?
3. If Solution #4 is the best way, how to handle a separate routing for this? I want the page to use the routing I set in app.js and only using the routing in back-end when calling api.

Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: Just an idea, you can use .net Core and a self-hosted Kestrel project, in this way the back-end can also serve the front-end as static content and can be in sepparate projects.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you should have 2 Virtual Applications running under the same website in IIS.  If you go into IIS you can create a website and then create a Virtual Application under it.  For example;

1. `www.company.com` Create a website called company.com
2. `www.company.com/app` Create a virtual application under company.com which is called app and this will be where your angular application lives
3. `www.company.com/api`Create a virtual application under company.com which is called api and this will be where your web API lives.  It can be a .NET application.

If you migrate to PHP you may have to tweak the website settings but it's still a good plan.

Comment: My current "template" of choice is very similar. I have been lucky and usually get to use 1 VS solution and different ports for different projects (web app vs api), but I would do it the way described here if I had the OP's requirements.

Comment: This solution means we have to install and configure IIS in user's PC. This will make the same problem with solution #3, an amateur user will have difficulty to do it.
We could make an installer that also configure IIS, but that means there will be a lot of process running on user's PC and we want to avoid that.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "in a different VS solution".  Does it need to be in a separate repository or source control? It's fairly easy to have 2 solutions which reference overlapping folders if they are in the same location etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have used @fireydude's virtual directory approach for a previous single-server **hosted** project, but if you are saying that you need to install the website itself on *each user's machine*, then yes, you will probably most easily achieve this using a self-hosted approach.

Look at OWIN self hosting, in particular you might look for sample code where people use self hosted approaches to implement their end-to-end integration tests - i have done this exact thing for my current project, but unfortunately it is proprietary code and I cannot share it here.

If you *forced* to use WebApi, take a look at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

On the otherhand, if you have the freedom to do so, I highly recommend that you take a look into the ServiceStack framework - It is excellent, very fast, with a nicer message-based API approach (similar to those endorsed by Amazon, Google etc)

http://docs.servicestack.net/self-hosting

Answer (score 0):

I have some how the same project structur, but i dont use angular. I hope i may help you.

I build the website in "visual studio code", and the back end (api) in "visual studio 2015". 
The Publish folder for the API is in the website release folder.

```
root/inetpup/sites/www.example.com
root/inetpup/sites/www.example.com/api
```

I use an IIS and transformed the www.example.com folder into an website.
The website is available on "www.example.com" and the api on "www.example.com/api".

At the front-end i need to request the date from the back end as follows:

```
www.example.com/api/items
```